# Parsing attribute name text from xml using xml.etree.elementTree

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

I'm not sure how i could get the values from   `<array name="logEntries" type="value" depth="1">` with the following code.

What i currently have so far, which works if have only **one** array tag on the xml, but not on multiple.

```
#Currently xml_input var is returned from an http request
root = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_input)
for child in root.findall('.array/value'):
    print(child)
```

XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Values version="2.0">
  <array name="logList" type="value" depth="1">
    <value>type_log</value>
  </array>
  <value name="numlines">2</value>
  <array name="numlinesList" type="value" depth="1">
    <value>2</value>
  </array>
  <array name="logEntries" type="value" depth="1">
    <value>some inputs</value>
    <value>other inputs</value>
  </array>
</Values>
```

Desired output:

```
some inputs
other inputs
```

In short, even consulting [The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) i'm unable to discover how can overcome this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works for me. I get all 4 `<value>`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for child in root.findall('.//array[@name="logEntries"]/value'):
    print(child.text)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.Thank you!